# How to select a target after the selected one?

Tags: regex

I'm using [Burp Suit](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to capture http response and replace the specific value.

For example, the text

```
item:["1.0|-2.0|3.0|99|5.0","2.0|5.0|7.0|99|7","10|11|12|99|14"]
```

I want to select the three 99
it's not a constant value
but they always at the fourth position in a item

my expected output is

```
item:["1.0|-2.0|3.0|0|5.0","2.0|5.0|7.0|0|7","10|11|12|0|14"]
```

this is my regex

```
"([0-9\.\-]*\|){3}
```

result:

> item:[**"1.0|-2.0|3.0|**99|5.0",**"2.0|5.0|7.0|**99|7",**"10|11|12|**99|14"]

I'm trying to use

```
(?<="([0-9\.\-]*\|){3})[0-9]*
```

but it seems to be invalid

Hope someone can help me
I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: I'm using the Burp Suite to get http response and replace something

Comment: I'm confused about the expected output you want.

Comment: I want to replace 99 to any other number I want, like 0

Comment: I suspect the reason is many regex-flavors (Perl, Python) only allow fixed-length strings in lookbehinds... If you are only out the replace them however, you can just convert to lookbegin to a subpattern (`1`), and replace it with `\1<yournewvalue>` (or whatever your syntax for references to subpatterns is).

Comment: Could you put a bit more code? As in how you're doing the replace.

Comment: @Jerry What I only need is using regex to match my target, and the program will replace it. But the problem is I can't find the correct regex condition to match my target :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems lookbehinds need fixed length strings. `*` in lookbehind won't work.

I am surprised why you need lookbehind here. Try searching for `("([0-9\.\-]*\|){3})([0-9]*)` and replace it with `$1${new_num}`

I am not aware of Burp Suit but can give you example in perl.

```
my $str = 'item:["1.0|-2.0|3.0|99|5.0","2.0|5.0|7.0|99|7","10|11|12|99|14"]';
my $new_num = 0;
$str =~ s/("([0-9\.\-]*\|){3})([0-9]*)/$1${new_num}/g;
print "${str}\n";
```

Output:

```
item:["1.0|-2.0|3.0|0|5.0","2.0|5.0|7.0|0|7","10|11|12|0|14"]
```

Check the same example in action [here](http://codepad.org/e308fyoE)

Comment: Thanks a lots for your answer :) But the program I use can't handle the subpattern. It can only match the target and change it, so I need lookbehind or other method without subpattern.

Comment: Oh.. my mistake. I found that it can handle subpattern. But the prefix is $, like $1. Thanks for your help! you save my day!

Comment: @user2804830 Oops I should have used `$1` instead of `\1`. Bdw, both works fine in case of perl, so didn't notice. Edited the code.

Comment: @user2804830 I did nothing special! You had 90% ans ready and could have solved this by yourself had you figured out support of subpattern earlier...